# Access to a variable in the app.config from a class C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, app-config

I'm working with a DataBase using C#. **My problem comes when I try to get a value from app.config to say with what database the project has to work**.

This is what I am trying:

```
namespace LanzamientoProyectos.BD
{
    public class ConsultasBD : IDisposable
    {
        private SqlConnection conexionBD;
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath); 
        string valEmp = config.AppSettings.Settings["EMPRESA"].Value;

        private const string Empresa = "3";

        public ConsultasBD()
        {
            conexionBD = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ggConnectionString"]);
        }
```

But all time I getting the next two errors:

> **Error 1**: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property
>
> **Error 2**: A field initializer cannot refer to the non-static field, method or property

**How can I access to this variable in the app.config in this class?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try and Google those error messages? There's plenty of answers on here that will help.

Comment: Of course, but I have tried all the things that I have seen and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Why wouldn't you store your connection strings where it should have been stored?

Comment: If you want to store the connection string in the app.config, I suggest that you can set the app.config in the current project instead of other places.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in these two lines:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath); 
string valEmp = config.AppSettings.Settings["EMPRESA"].Value;
```

C# doesn't allow you to refer to other fields (`config` in this case) in this way. If you want to access `config`, you'll have to do it in the constructor or any other method.

Maybe a look at the documentation is helpful here: [Compiler Error CS0236](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236).

> If you are trying to initialize a variable outside a method, consider performing the initialization inside the class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do the initializations inside the constructor:

```
public class ConsultasBD : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection conexionBD{get;set;};
    Configuration config = null; 
    string valEmp = String.Empty;
    private const string Empresa = "3";

    public ConsultasBD()
    {
        config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath); 
        valEmp  = config.AppSettings.Settings["EMPRESA"];
        conexionBD = new SqlConnection(config.AppSettings["ggConnectionString"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access to this variable in the app.config in this class?

You had it correct in the second usage in your example.

Access the value like this:

```
string valEmp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMPRESA"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're storing your connection string right there where it should be stored:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EMPRESA" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMPRESA;Integrated Security=True"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["EMPRESA"].ConnectionString;
```